# Polymorphic Types and IXmlSerializable

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

The XML serialization in .NET allows polymorphic objects through the `extraTypes[]` parameter of the `XmlSerializer` constructor. It also allows customization of XML serialization for types that implement `IXmlSerializable`.

However, I’m unable to combine these two features – as demonstrated in this minimal example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace CsFoo
{
    public class CustomSerializable : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }
        public void ReadXml(XmlReader xr) { }
        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter xw) { }
    }

    class CsFoo
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(
                typeof(object),
                new Type[] { typeof(CustomSerializable) });

        xs.Serialize(new StringWriter(), new CustomSerializable());
    }
}
```

The last line throws `System.InvalidOperationException` with this message:

> The type CsFoo.CustomSerializable may not be used in this context to
>   use CsFoo.CustomSerializable as a parameter, return
>   type, or member of a class or struct, the parameter, return
>   type, or member must be declared as type CsFoo.CustomSerializable
>   (it cannot be object). Objects of type CsFoo.CustomSerializable
>   may not be used in un-typed collections, such as ArrayLists.

Wading through the dynamically generated XML assemblies, we ultimately come back to .NET standard library code by calling:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(
     String, String, Object, Boolean) : Void
```

In turn, this leads to:

```
protected Exception CreateUnknownTypeException(Type type)
{
    if (typeof(IXmlSerializable).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    {
        return new InvalidOperationException(
            Res.GetString("XmlInvalidSerializable",
            new object[] { type.FullName }));
    }

    // Rest omitted...
```

Reflector shows that the `XmlInvalidSerializable` resource corresponds with the string above – i.e.,  `WriteTypedPrimitive` doesn’t like `IXmlSerializable`.

If we generate a non-polymorphic serializer, like so:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomSerializable));
```

.NET will generate a call to:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteSerializable(
    IXmlSerializable, String, String, Boolean) : Void
```

This handles `IXmlSerializable` properly. Does anybody know why .NET doesn’t use this function in the polymorphic case? Looking at the C# that the XML serializer generates, it appears to me this can be done quite easily. Here's some code I got from the XML serializer, with an untested solution:

```
void Write1_Object(string n, string ns, global::System.Object o, 
   bool isNullable, bool needType)
{
    if ((object)o == null)
    {
        if (isNullable) WriteNullTagLiteral(n, ns);
        return;
    }
    if (!needType)
    {
        System.Type t = o.GetType();
        if (t == typeof(global::System.Object))
        {
        }
>>> patch begin <<<
+         else if (typeof(IXmlSerializable).IsAssignableFrom(t))
+         {
+             WriteSerializable((System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable)
                   ((global::CsFoo.CustomSerializable)o), 
+                  @"CustomSerializable", @"", true, true);
+         }
>>> patch end <<<
        else
        {
            WriteTypedPrimitive(n, ns, o, true);
            return;
        }
    }
    WriteStartElement(n, ns, o, false, null);
    WriteEndElement(o);
}
```

Is this left out for technical reasons or just a feature limitation? Unsupported feature, or my idiocy? My intertubes Google skills fail me.

I did find some related questions here, with "[C# Xml-Serializing a derived class using IXmlSerializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527902/c-xml-serializing-a-derived-class-using-ixmlserializable)" being most relevant. It leads me to believe that it's simply not possible.

In that case, my current thought is to inject a default `IXmlSerializable` implementation in the root base class. Then everything will be an `IXmlSerializable`, and .NET won't complain. I can use Reflection.Emit to whip out the `ReadXml` and `WriteXml` bodies for each concrete types, generating XML that would look the same as it would if I used the library one.

Some people, when confronted with an XML serialization problem, think "I know, I'll use Reflection.Emit to generate code." Now they have two problems.

---

P.S. Note; I'm aware of alternatives to .NET's XML serialization, and know it has limitations. I also know that saving a POCO is vastly simpler than dealing with abstract data types. But I've got a pile of legacy code, and need support for existing XML schemas.

So while I appreciate replies that show how easy this is in `SomeOtherXML`, `YAML`, `XAML`, `ProtocolBuffers`, `DataContract`, `RandomJsonLibrary`, `Thrift`, or your `MorseCodeBasedSerializeToMp3` library - hey I might learn something -, what I'm hoping for is an XML serializer work-around, if not solution.

Comment: Although a pretty late addition, anyway: the solution with extra types doesn't work for me in the case of IXmlSerializable. However [this approach](http://www.softwarerockstar.com/2006/12/using-ixmlserializable-to-overcome-not-expected-error-on-derived-classes/) is working, as it allows the deserialized class be different from the property class (!), so any custom logic finding the right type to create can be implemented that way.

Comment: There is another solution declared [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/422577/incorrect-deserialization-of-polymorphic-type-that-implements-ixmlserializable) (using `XmlSchemaProvider` attribute to bind xml types to the .net types), but it lacks the code, and I was not able to make that idea work. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce your problem, when using `object`:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(object),
    new Type[] { typeof(CustomSerializable) });
```

However, I then created a derived class of `CustomSerializable`:

```
public class CustomSerializableDerived : CustomSerializable
{
}
```

And tried to serialize it:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(CustomSerializable),
    new Type[] { typeof(CustomSerializableDerived) });
```

This worked.

So, it would appear that the problem is restricted to the case where you specify "object" as the type to serialize, but not if you specify a concrete base type.

I'll do some more research on this in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

First of all posters statement

> The XML serialization in .NET allows polymorphic objects through the extraTypes[] parameter of the XmlSerializer constructor.

is misleading. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) extratypes is used for:

> If a **property** or **field returns** an **array**, the extraTypes parameter specifies objects that can be inserted into the array.

Meaning that if somewhere in your serialized object graph polymorphic objects are returned via array, they can be processed.

While I haven't really found a solution how to serialize a polymorphic type as root XML object, I was able to serialize polymorphic types found in object graph using either standard XML serializer or IXmlSerializable. See below for my solution:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace CsFoo
{
  public class Foo
  {
    [XmlElement("BarStandard", typeof(BarStandardSerializable))]
    [XmlElement("BarCustom", typeof(BarCustomSerializable))]
    public Bar BarProperty { get; set; }
  }

  public abstract class Bar
  { }

  public class BarStandardSerializable : Bar
  { }

  public class BarCustomSerializable : Bar, IXmlSerializable
  {
    public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader xr) { }
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter xw) { }
  }

  class CsFoo
  {
    static void Main()
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        Foo f1 = new Foo() { BarProperty = new BarCustomSerializable() };
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));

        xs.Serialize(sw, f1);
        StringReader sr= new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Foo f2 = (Foo)xs.Deserialize(sr);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that using either

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo), 
            new Type[] { typeof(BarStandardSerializable),
            typeof(BarCustomSerializable)});
```

or

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(BarCustomSerializable))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(BarStandardSerializable))]
public abstract class Bar
{ }
```

without XmlElement defined, would cause the code to fail at serialization.

Comment: Note to future readers: if `BarProperty` is something like an array `[XmlArrayItem(/* ... */)]` must be used instead of `[XmlElement(/* ... */)]`

Answer (score 0):

In order for IxmlSerializable to work, the class needs to have a null constructor.

Consider  a base class

- MyBaseXmlClass:IXmlSerializable
  -- implement GetSchema
- MyXmlClass:MyBaseXmlClass
  --  ReadXml
- - WriteXml

Comment: -1: His does have a default constructor; you could use actual code instead of just text to illustrate your point.